# R handle null string using sapply

Tags: r, null, sapply

I need to cleansing the data that contain the value of '' (a null value of string). There are two things I will do next:
  1. Counting the number of null string value.
  2. Replacing them with NA value

However, there are some problem to accomplish the work. I tried 
using the sapply function with the function of isBlank (identifying the null
srting value). It doesn't return the value of TRUE/FALSE for each element but
for each column. Thus I can't use the colSums function to do the job.

I'm not sure if it could be the string manipulation function as a parameter to 
sapply, could anyone help me with it?

```
isBlank=function(x){
  if(!is.na(x) && x==''){
    return(TRUE)
  }else{
    return(FALSE)             
  }   
}

sapply(train,isBlank)
```

Comment: You need `&` instead of `&&`.  We can do this easily with `!is.na(train) & train==""`

Comment: Your way is absolutely suitable for this case , Nevertheless I just wondering why the sapply doens't work with the function of isBlank.  Anyway, I'm appreciated for your great help!

Comment: It wont work because You are `return`ing a single TRUE/FALSE per each column instead of each element

Comment: Could it be possible to use the <pre> sapply<code> function that  returning each element

Answer (score 0):

If it is a data.frame, we can do this without looping by converting to `logical` matrix

```
i1 <- !is.na(train) & train==""
```

and then `replace` the blanks (`""`) to NA

```
replace(train, i1, NA)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
train <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, "", 1:5), 5*5, 
           replace=TRUE), ncol=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the understandable illustration.  Got it totally.

Comment: Although I'v been using stackoverflow to solve many R questions, I'm still new to the forum.  I was trying to finish the question but can't find the botton,lol.